# Bootstrap's `col .col-md-4` class does not work when using `img-fluid`

Tags: bootstrap-4, responsive

I want my divs to stack when I resize my window- therefore I am using `col .col-md-4`. Inside my column with that used tag, I have an image, my screen stacks as expected when I resize my window. HOWEVER when I add the `img-fluid` class in my  tag, the `col .col-md-4` div stacking upon window resizing stops working.

Div Stacking WORKING WITHOUT `img-fluid` class:

I tried removing the `img-fluid` class and added width: 100% for the image instead, this also stops the div stacking from working.

```html
<div class="row">
  <div id="browImageContainer" class="col .col-md-4">
    <img class="browImage " src="/images/powderBrowSample.png">
  </div>
  <div class="col .col-md-4 border">
    content
  </div>
</div>
```

Div stacking NOT WORKING WITH `img-fluid` class:

```html
<div id="servicesRectangle"></div>
<div class="row">
  <div id="browImageContainer" class="col .col-md-4">
    <img class="browImage img-fluid" src="/images/powderBrowSample.png">
  </div>
  <div class="col .col-md-4 border">
    content
  </div>
</div>
```

Summary: I want my divs to stack when I use the img-fluid tag! But it doesnt!

Expected Results:

Divs to stack while using the `img-fluid` class to make my image responsive.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to remove the dot before the col-md-4 class. Thats an invalid selector. Classes  always be written without the dot before in HTML.

Then it should work like expected. Its not about img-fluid.

Answer (score 0):

Why you have `dot` in your class names (`col .col-md-4`)?

you didn't use the correct class names: `col col-md-4`

Answer (score 0):

I got what I needed by removing the `col` and `col-md-4` classes completely and substituting it with the `col-sm` class.